# The requested URL /test/index.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, wamp

I am getting an error while running a PHP project.

```
The requested URL /test/index.php was not found on this server.
```

Wamp sever icon is green and `loclhost:81` is still accessible.

I am using `netBeans 7.3.1`

Comment: Not enough info here.

Comment: Yep. Not enough info. What are we supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem once before.

As the error says, url was not found, see your `www` folder if it exists there.

Remember that `netBeans` creates project folder inside `..Documents\NetBeansProjects`, move that project to `www`

Comment: I moved my php project to the WampServer's www folder. But still I get the same error of 404. My wamp icon is also green.